Where does n+1 come from in the formula for Catalan numbers? Why is it not n?
Consider sequences of X's and Y's, where we can form a Dyck word only if every prefix has at least as many X's as Y's
Now consider this argument: for any sequence consisting equally of X's and Y's (the C(2n, n) part of the formula), we can rotate the array n different ways. One of these n rotations will be a Dyck word.
Where is the flaw in this argument? And what's the correct argument that leads us to n+1?

Why does only 1 of these n rotations become a Dyck word? EG If we have XYXXYY, there are at least 2 rotations that work.

Though I am familiar with Dyck words, I don't understand what you mean by your first sentence : how can prefixes have as many Xs and Ys ? Please give examples.

see here

@JeanMarie XYYX has a prefix with 2 Y's and 1 X, making it an invalid Dyck word. If we rotate it to XXYY, there are no prefixes with more Y's than X's, so one of n rotations is a valid Dyck word

@CalvinLin That's a good counterexample. But if more than 1 rotation is valid, then why is the catalan fraction less than 1/n not more? How do we get 1/(n+1)?

1/ Because there are 2n ways to rotate the word. 2/ Because of double counting, so not all words are weighted equally. IE Out of the 2 rotations of XYXYXY, 1 of them is valid. 3/ The ratio of 1/(n+1) falls out naturally from the exceedance proof.

How do you get 2n, is it because you also include reflections and not just pure rotations?
Also, I'm a bit confused about the exceedance proof. It says that because the exceedance is capped at n, |exc(n)| = |exc(n-1)|, and exc 0 is valid, only 1/(n+1) are valid, i.e. 0 exceedance. But when considering all C(2n, n) sequences of equal Xs and Ys, don't some sequences have negative exceedance? Like XXXYYY has 3 extra X's at one point. So why is it 1/(n+1) that are valid, not n/(2n+1)?
